# Font-stretch property not working on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

```css
.bord {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-stretch: extra-condensed;
}
```

```html
<div class="bord">
  Hello, there is an error in your code. Also the content does not condense as desired
</div>
```

The class `bord` contains `font-stretch` css property but doesn't seem to work on IE11

Comment: Whether or not it works in IE11, you might just want to avoid it, as it doesn't work in Chrome, which is a sizeable chunk of the internet: http://caniuse.com/#search=font-stretch

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-stretch/), here is why :

> In order to use `font-stretch` and see a result of some kind, the font
>   being used has to have a face that matches the value given. In other
>   words, `font-stretch` will not work on just any font, but only on fonts
>   that are designed with different faces matching the defined sizes.

so this is **not** an IE11 issue.

#### here is a snippet with your code (no font set):

```css
.bord {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-stretch: extra-condensed;
}
```

```html
<div class="bord">
  Hello, there is an error in your code. Also the content does not condense as desired
</div>
```

#### here is a snippet with font set (that can be stretched/condensed):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: arial;
}
.bord {
  font-stretch: extra-condensed;
}
```

```html
<div class="bord">
  Hello, there is an error in your code. Also the content does not condense as desired
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  Hello, there is an error in your code. Also the content does not condense as desired
</div>
```

#### Note:

- Remember this is CSS3 property, and still not widely used in browsers, only IE9+ and Firefox 9+.

Comment: So DO you mean, if I use Font-family: Arial and then use font-stretch:condensed... then it would work in IE11 ??? I dont think so, it would work. Because, here even though in my example I havent used any Font-family..but in real, the code I am using on IE11 does have font-family : arial and font-stretch :extra-condesnsed. And still it is not working on IE11

Comment: can you please show your "real" code then? have you run both my snippets in IE11?

Comment: StackOverflow still beats ChatGPT ♥