# Adapt font stretch to div size with CSS

Tags: css

how could i fit the font stretch to div size with css similar to an image with a height and width?
maybe something like:

```html
.div p{
 font-stretch: div(100%);
 transform: div(100%);
}
```

[stretch letters effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvuJq.jpg)

I need javascript?

Comment: There are some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font-stretch property not working on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552426/font-stretch-property-not-working-on-ie11)

Answer (score 0):

> use **clamp** it is alter native for *media query*

```
font-size : clamp(10px, 25px, 50px)
```

Comment: thanks friend, I have tried it, but clamp does not manage to deform the text.

Comment: instead of px use the value in vw .